# Get the element matched by the selector argument to jQuery on()

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

**HTML**

```
<div id="test">
    <form method="post">
        <button name="type" value="add">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
        <button name="type" value="subtract">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').on('click', 'form button', function (event) {
        console.log(event.target.tagName);
        console.log(event.target.value);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I want to be able to see which button has been clicked - the "add" button or the "subtract" button. However, depending on where you click on the `button` element, the click event that bubbles may have been on the `button` itself, or on the `span` inside it.

**Sample Console Output**

```
BUTTON
subtract
SPAN
undefined
BUTTON
add
SPAN
undefined
```

What is the best way to get the element that matched the `'form button'` selector I specified in the `selector` argument passed to the `on()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery` binds `this` to the matching element:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').on('click', 'form button', function (event) {
        console.log(this.tagName);
        console.log(this.value);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/3jEZA/1/)

From the jQuery docs:

> When jQuery calls a handler, the `this` keyword is a reference to the element where the event is being delivered; for directly bound events this is the element where the event was attached and for delegated events `this` is an element matching `selector`. (Note that `this` may not be equal to `event.target` if the event has bubbled from a descendant element.) To create a jQuery object from the element so that it can be used with jQuery methods, use `$( this )`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `closest()` which will match either the element referenced by `closest()` selector or any of it's descendents

```
$('#test').on('click', 'form button', function (event) {
   var $button=$(event.target).closest('button');
    console.log($button.val());        
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Edit: Not sure why I followed the target approach in original question. Using `this` makes far more sense. However there are cases where you want to determine if target is selector or a descendent so leaving answer as is

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/W8KC7/)**</kbd>